# Axios error handler message with async/await in the react

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

My app requests axios from the react to the nestjs server, and the code is here.

```
const loginEvent = async (id, password) => {
    try {
      const res = await (await axios.post('users/login', { id, password })).data;
      if (res.success) {
         ...
      } else {
         ...
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Login Err ', err);
    }
  };
```

In Postman, I could see properly including messages and success.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "statusCode": 400,
    "timestamp": "2022-05-17T11:50:16.676Z",
    "path": "/users/login",
    "message": [
        "id should not be empty"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

However, only brief error messages are displayed in React.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/login 400 (Bad Request)
Login Err  Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

When an error occurs in the request, the server sends a handled messages and success = false, but neither was found in the response of axios using async/wait.

If i don't use async/wait, I can check both at axios.post.then.catch(), but I want to use async/wait to make the code cleaner. What should I do?

Comment: You might be returning HTTP status 400 that's why it's going into `catch`. And this is correct, you just need to handle this case in `catch` instead of `try`.

Comment: @ShivamSharma But I want to display different messages to see if the ID is wrong, if the password is wrong, or if the connection to the server is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server send the array message, you should be able to get them in the response object in your error, as below:

```js
async function loginEvent() {
  try {
    const res = await (await axios.post('users/login')).data
    // your code
  } catch (e: any) {
if(e.response != undefined) {
   const statusCode = e.response.status // 400
   const statusText = e.response.statusText // Bad Request
   // whereby errorMessage is the error message returned by your server
   // Example of an error message 'Incorrect username or pwd'
   return {success: false, message:e.response.data.errorMessage}
}
return {success:false, message:'Action failed on platform because of ' + e.message}
    
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote the code in this answer as it was, but it was not solved. But what happened was resolved half an hour later. Thank you.